# Copy and modify values in Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am doing a job in regular basis. Now I just want to automate that job by using VBScript.

**QUERY**

I just wanted to copy one excel file from folder A to another folder B which has been created today and want to change a value.

**Condition**

- I don't want same file to copy twice.
- And I want to change the values in column H as 1 instead of 0.

Hope i am clear.

Could anyone please help me on this?

Regards,

Nanthini

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below link woould help you. 
And if it doesnot could you please eloberate your question.

http://easyprograming.com/vb-script-articles/17-moving-and-renaming-files-in-vb-script/

And to change the values of columns you can use the below code:

```
excelPath = "<<Path>>"  'Excel Path
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'Excel object
Set currentWorkSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("<<Sheet name>>")
left = currentWorksheet.UsedRange.Column
Set Cells = currentWorksheet.Cells
'loop to iterate through all th columns
For row = 0 to (usedRowsCount-1)
 Cells(row,8).Value = "1"
Next
```